# r/rmarkdown/knitr: How to add an evaluate r chunk to a figure legend?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

In the context of a "fig_caption: true" in the yaml header, I am trying to embed the output of code snippets in a caption along the lines of

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.caption="This is my caption `r paste('A','B')`;"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

However, the result is that the r snippet/chunk is being printed *verbatim*, rather than evaluated. Is what I strive to do even currently feasible?

Comment: not tried this but try putting the whole caption into paste. Something like fig.caption = `r paste("This is my caption", A, B)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://yihui.name/knitr/options/ by @Yihui:

> eval.after: (fig.cap) a character vector of option names; these
>   options will be evaluated after a chunk is evaluated, and all other
>   options will be evaluated before a chunk (e.g. for chunk option
>   fig.cap=paste('p-value is', t.test(x)$p.value), it will be evaluated
>   after the chunk according to the value of x if eval.after='fig.cap')

In short, to make your `paste` work, use `eval.after='fig.cap'` like this

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "chinsoon12"
date: "April 21, 2016"
output: 
  html_document:
    fig_caption: true
---


```{r, echo=FALSE}
A <- "A"
B <- "B"
```


```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, eval.after='fig.cap', fig.cap=paste("This is my caption", A)}
A <- "A"
B <- "B"
plot(cars)
```
````

You might also want to check out these:

1. [Inserting Captions and Cross References in a R Markdown Document by Andy Lyons](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/98310_b44bc54001af49d98a7b891d204652e2.html)
2. [Figure and Table Captions in Markdown by fishR Blog](http://www.r-bloggers.com/figure-and-table-captions-in-markdown/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the links;